# Python ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (5,) (128,)

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, face-recognition

I want it to recognise my face whenever the program is run.

I am getting this error only when I use the for loop, If I don't use the for loop and get the data from the database and hardcode the values, I am not getting any errors and the program is running fine.

The program that i wrote is:

```
import face_recognition
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pymongo

#connecting to the database

client = pymongo.MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017')
db = client['attendence_system']
collections = db['students']


video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)


known_face_names = []
known_face_encodings = [] 
array_faces = []
data = collections.find()
for i in data:
    array_faces.append(face_recognition.load_image_file(f"static/images/{i['img_file']}"))
    known_face_encodings.append(face_recognition.face_encodings(image)[0] for image in array_faces)
    known_face_names.append(i['name'])


print(known_face_names)
print(known_face_encodings)



while True:
    
    ret, frame = video_capture.read()
    rgb_frame = np.ascontiguousarray(frame[:, :, ::-1])

    face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(rgb_frame)
    face_encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(rgb_frame, face_locations)

    for (top, right, bottom, left), face_encoding in zip(face_locations, face_encodings):
        matches = face_recognition.compare_faces(known_face_encodings, face_encoding)

        name = "Unknown"

        face_distances = face_recognition.face_distance(known_face_encodings, face_encoding)
        best_match_index = np.argmin(face_distances)

        print(best_match_index,matches)
        if matches[best_match_index]:
            name = known_face_names[best_match_index]

        # Draw a box around the face
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (left, top), (right, bottom), (0, 0, 255), 2)

        # Draw a label with a name below the face
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (left, bottom - 35), (right, bottom), (0, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)
        font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX
        cv2.putText(frame, name, (left + 6, bottom - 6), font, 1.0, (255, 255, 255), 1)

    # Display the resulting image
    cv2.imshow('Project', frame)

    # Hit 'q' on the keyboard to quit!
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# Release handle to the webcam
video_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

When I run thew program these are the errors that I am getting :

```
File "/Users/Desktop/test_app/capture.py", line 65, in <module>
    matches = face_recognition.compare_faces(known_face_encodings, face_encoding)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/face_recognition/api.py", line 226, in compare_faces
    return list(face_distance(known_face_encodings, face_encoding_to_check) <= tolerance)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/face_recognition/api.py", line 75, in face_distance
    return np.linalg.norm(face_encodings - face_to_compare, axis=1)
                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (5,) (128,)
```

Comment: `face_encodings` and `face_to_compare` are arrays of different shape so the subtraction operation is not defined for those arrays. If you don't plan on using broadcasting, this is an error, you should check why those arrays have different shape. Also you do not provide the code of the `face_recognition` module